# Find max value in row and fill new column with that columns name using Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
Index, cat1, cat2, cat3
1,0.3,0.1,0.4
2,0.5,0.1,0.2
3,0.1,0.4,0.3
```

I want to create a fifth column "max_cat" with the column name of the category with the highest value like so:

```
Index, cat1, cat2, cat3, max_cat
1,0.3,0.1,0.4, cat3
2,0.5,0.1,0.2, cat1
3,0.1,0.4,0.3, cat2
```

How would I go about achieving that, preferably using Pandas?

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
data = StringIO("""
Index, cat1, cat2, cat3
1,0.3,0.1,0.4
2,0.5,0.1,0.2
3,0.1,0.4,0.3
""")
df = pd.read_csv(data, skiprows=1, header=0, names=["cat1","cat2","cat3"])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are not worrying about ties, then you can use [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html#pandas.DataFrame.idxmax), with `axis=1` on the `cati` columns:

```
>>> df['max_cat'] = df[['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3']].idxmax(axis=1)
>>> df
   Index  cat1  cat2  cat3 max_cat
0      1   0.3   0.1   0.4    cat3
1      2   0.5   0.1   0.2    cat1
2      3   0.1   0.4   0.3    cat2
```

if you want to see the ties, then see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27219916/625914).

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean by not worrying about ties?

Comment: In case of ties, `idxmax` returns the first occurence it sees.